# HTACCESS "https" DETECTION?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https, amazon-ec2

From `.htaccess` I can NOT detect whether `https` or not.

What i simply need is, if i hit:

- "**http**://www.example.com" --go to--> "http://www.pure-site.com"
- "**https**://www.example.com" --go to--> "https://www.secure-site.com"

In my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.secure-site.com [R=301,L,NS]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.pure-site.com [R=301,L,NS]
```

But it can **NEVER DETECT** `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on`.
I'm on Load-balanced AWS/EC2 instances.

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576142/htaccess-https-redirection?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

If understood you correctly, this should do the job.

For https:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} ^on$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.yourdomain/$1 [R,L]
```

For http:

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP} ^on$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain/$1 [R,L]
```